# How to clear all the cache in Riverpod

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I have created an App in Flutter using river-pod, but the problem arises is when I login from user1 and logout and then log back in using User2, the data shown is still of user1. So i want to change it so that the data shown is of User2 (it can be by clearing the cache which seems like the most viable option for me).

I have looked out for some solutions on Stack-overflow itself but i was unable to catch onto them as they were outdated and I wasn't able to understand the rest of the solutions

Comment: Post your login and logout riverpod's provider codes here.

Comment: Post a code to understand more.

Comment: ` void signInWithGoogle(BuildContext context, bool isFromLogin) async {
    state = true;
    final user = await _authRepository.signInWithGoogle(isFromLogin);
    state = false;
    user.fold(
        (l) => showSnackBar(context, l.message),
        (userModel) => {
              _ref.read(userProvider.notifier).update((state) => userModel),
            });
  }` The signinwithgoogle function in AuthRepository is normal Authentication SignIn method from Google

I am using Firebase as database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your data dependent on your user. Something like:

```dart
final userProvider = Provider((ref) => User(...));

// information relating to the user
...
final dataProvider = Provider((ref) {
  ref.watch(userProvider);
  return data;
});
...
final otherDataProvider = Provider((ref) {
  ref.watch(userProvider);
  return otherData;
});
```

Comment: I have created userProvider which updates on AuthChanges and changes usermodel accordingly but my problem is that i am unable to update other features, such as Home Page data and friends data

Comment: You should probably reconsider the architecture of your application

Comment: I am trying to dispose the data in provider using autodispose but it is very inconsistent, how should i manually dispose it whenever i want it to?

Comment: use `ref.refresh(provider);` or `ref.invalidate(provider);`. This will reset the provider state.

Comment: How do I use this in a widget like a button or something?

Comment: You can use this on the "logout" button

Comment: yes it did but i had to improvise and use refresh in after user signin instead of log out